# how to get file name from caller for ruby cgi

Tags: ruby, cgi

I want to get file name that require

index.rb

```
puts "<html><head></head><body>"

require 'test.rb'

puts "</body></html>"
```

test.rb

```
# here I want to get 'index.rb' to go to the case select statement to change output html

puts <<"EOS"
<p> HTML output bla bla bla </p>
EOS
```

maybe it's possible using caller class but i couldn't find out.

Comment: Take a look at [`Kernel.caller_locations`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. i got it.

caller_locations(3).first.path

Comment: Write an answer to your question and accept it so that future readers can easily resolve the same problem as well.

Comment: It's probably a really bad idea to go down the road of using CGI which is a technology that fell out of favor in the 1990s. Tools like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) make this significantly less messy.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

```
filename = caller_locations(3).first.path
```

the number should be changed depends on the depth.

thanks ndn